# Problem connecting pi from external network

Tags: networking, motion

so I'm setting up a motion server(to get a live feed of my house over the internet) and everything works fine as long as I connect to the video feed from another machine while on the same network.
My problem is that, if I try to check it when not on the same network, it just doesn't work.
I have forwarded port 8080-8081 on my router.(that let me use it on other devices on the local network)
I also have a static IP already.
Does anyone have an idea what the problem might be?

im on a pi3 b+ btw
also the pi is connected to the router through wifi if that has anything to do with it.

edit 1: I have also opened the ports in the firewall and have checked that they are listening

Comment: The Pi appears to be irrelevant to the question.  Look at such as https://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/how-to-setup-a-webcam-and-access-it-from-anywhere/

Comment: Your question is unclear. You should revise it if you hope to get a good answer. E.G. `if I try to check it when not on the same network, it just doesn't work` ??? why don't you put it on the same network? `I also have a static IP already.` ??? what has that got to do with it?